# Why my app spring batch does not process all data and sometimes write in differents cvs files of the partitions

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring boot and spring batch application, which when reading from db it getting the records and each one has 3 attributes: usernetwork, agenttype, accounts. The accounts field is a chain of accounts separated by a character for query and then make use of an existing web service, which the agenttype field brings a letter that identifies the type of form that will be used on phones provider's cell phones. The letters is portfolio manangement and usernetwork is the user of phone cell. 
Example: usernetwork:RD74,agenttype:MRD74,accoounts:!34!55!67! 
usernetwork:RD74,agenttype:SRD74,accounts:!30!120!
usernetwork:RD75,agenttype:ORD75,accounts:!45!9555!2121!
usernetwork:RD5,agenttype:PRD5,accounts:!347!894!459!
My issue is that does not process all data and I dont know why.

This is the bean beanCustomer.

```
public class beanCustomer {

private String usernetwork;
private String tipoagente;
private String cuenta;
...//getters and setters
}
```

This is the bean beanAccountCollect.

```
public class beanAccountCollect {

private String usernetwork;
private String tipoagente;
private CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanParameter> lbparam2;
//getters and setters…
}
```

This is CustomerItemProcessor.

```
@Component
public class CustomerItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<beangenerico,ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>>> {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomerItemProcessor.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customerService")
    private CustomerService customerService;
    private ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>> listbean = new       ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>>();

    public ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>> process(beangenerico rangos) throws Exception {
      listbean.set(new CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>());
      if(listbean.get() != null) {
                //customer.setId(currentCustomer.getId());
                return listbean;
         } else {
                return null;
     }
}
```

Here is CustomerDAOImpl.

```
@Repository("customerDAO")
public class CustomerDAOImpl  implements CustomerDAO{

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomerDAOImpl.class);
private String SP_SQL = "{call mispAccountsbyBucket(?, ?)}";
private ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>> customerList2=new ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>>();
private beanCustomer b = null; 

public  ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>> getAccAgentes(beangenerico bean) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                customerList2.set(new CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>());

                return getJdbcTemplate().query(
                        SP_SQL,
                        new Object [] {bean.getIni(),bean.getFin()}, new ResultSetExtractor<ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>>>() {    

                            @Override
                            public ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>> extractData(ResultSet rs)
                                    throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                while(rs.next()){
                                b = new beanCustomer();
                                b.setUsernetwork(rs.getString("user_network"));//user for movil g80
                                b.setCuenta(rs.getString("cuenta"));//account for query ex: !34!56!67!566!445!
                                b.setTipoagente(rs.getString("tipoagente"));//example: MG80,TG80
                                customerList2.get().add(b);
                                }

                                return customerList2;
                            }
                        });
            }catch(Exception e) {
                logger.error("failed!",e);
            }
            return customerList2;

    }

@Autowired
public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}

public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
    if (null == jdbcTemplate) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }   
}
```

This is of the BeanAccountItemProcessor.

```
public class BeanAccountItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>>, ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanAccountCollect>>>{

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BeanAccountItemProcessor.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("beanAccountService")
    private BeanAccountService beanAccountService;

    private ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanAccountCollect>> listbeanAC = new ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanAccountCollect>>();

    @Override
    public ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanAccountCollect>> process(ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>> lstbeanagentecuenta) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listbeanAC.set(new CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanAccountCollect>());

        listbeanAC = beanAccountService.getGetDatosBean(lstbeanagentecuenta);

            if(listbeanAC != null) {

                logger.info("sise: "+listbeanAC.get().size());
                listbeanAC.get().forEach(g->{
                    String tipage = g.getTipoagente();
                    int sise = g.getLbparam2()!=null?g.getLbparam2().size():0;
                    logger.info(tipage+"- silst: "+sise);

                });


                return listbeanAC;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
    }
public void setBeanAccountService(BeanAccountService beanAccountService) {
        this.beanAccountService = beanAccountService;
    }

}
```

This is the BeanAccountDAOImpl.

```
@Repository("beanAccountDAO")
public class BeanAccountDAOImpl implements BeanAccountDAO{

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BeanAccountDAOImpl.class);

private String tablaHTML;
private String tbhist;
private String tbdescm;
private beanAccountCollect bacc_collect;

@Override
public ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanAccountCollect>> getGetDatosBean(ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanCustomer>> beanC) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {

                    lsbeancoll2.set(new CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanAccountCollect>());
                            for(beanCustomer b : beanC.get() ) 
                            {   
                                bacc_collect = new beanAccountCollect();
                                bacc_collect.setCuentas(b.getCuenta());
                                bacc_collect.setTipoagente(b.getTipoagente());
                                bacc_collect.setUsernetwork(b.getUsernetwork());

                                CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanParameter> lbp2 = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanParameter>();

                                bacc_collect.setLbparam2(getJdbcTemplate().query(SP_SQL, new Object[] {b.getCuenta()}, new ResultSetExtractor<CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanParameter>>()
                                {
                                public CopyOnWriteArrayList<beanParameter> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,DataAccessException {

                                    while(rs.next()){

                                        beanParameter bp = new beanParameter();
                                        bp.setState(rs.getString("state_info")==null?"":rs.getString("state_info"));
                                            bp.setAddress(rs.getString("ADDRESS_INFO");
                                            bp.setPostalCode(rs.getString("ZIP_ICO"));
                                            bp.setNameCustomer(rs.getString("CLIENTE"));
                                            bp.setSaldoCte(rs.getString("totaldebt"));
                                            bp.setSaldoRegularizar(rs.getString("lastreg"));
                                            bp.setPhoneTable(rs.getString("phones")); //                                                          
                                            bp.setPagoRegistrado(rs.getString("lastdebt"));
                                            bp.setPayDateRecord(rs.getString("paydate"));    

                                            lbp2.add(bp);       
                                      }
                             return lbp2;
                           }

                   }));

                  lsbeancoll2.get().add(bacc_collect);
              }//fin ciclo for

           }catch(Exception e) {                
                logger.error("failed! ",e);
         }
        return lsbeancoll2;
}

@Autowired
public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}

public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
    if (null == jdbcTemplate) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
return jdbcTemplate;
}
```

Here is my ConfigJob.

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
@Import({DBConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan({"com.mycompany.batch.config","com. mycompany.batch.dao","com. mycompany.batch.mapper","com.mycompany.batch.model","com. mycompany.batch.particion","com. mycompany.batch.procesos","com. mycompany.batch.reader","com. mycompany.batch.writers","com. mycompany.batch.service"})
public class ConfigJob  
//<T>
{

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("sqlserverDataSource")
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
Environment env;
@Bean(name = "demoPartitionStep")
public Step step1Manager(Step slaveStep) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1.manager")
            .<String, String>partitioner("step1", demoPartitioner())
            .step(slaveStep)
            .gridSize(numerohilos())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}

@Bean(name = "demoPartitioner", destroyMethod = "")
public Partitioner demoPartitioner() {
    RangePartitioner partitioner = new RangePartitioner();
        //partitioner.setDataSource(dataSource);
        // partitioner.partition(20);
      return partitioner;
    }

@Bean
public Step slaveStep(ItemReader<beangenerico> demoReader,ItemWriter tempRecordsWriter)
    {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("slaveStep")
                .chunk(1)
                .reader(demoReader)
                .processor(compositeProcessor())
                .writer(tempRecordsWriter)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();
}

@Bean
public CompositeItemProcessor compositeProcessor() {
        List<ItemProcessor> delegates = new ArrayList<>(3);
        delegates.add(CustomerProccesor());

        delegates.add(BeanAccountItemProcessor());
        delegates.add(beanDataItemProccesor());

        CompositeItemProcessor processor = new CompositeItemProcessor();

        processor.setDelegates(delegates);

        return processor;
}

@Bean
public CustomerItemProcessor CustomerProccesor(){
        return new CustomerItemProcessor();
}

@Bean
public AccountsItemProcessor AccountsItemProcessor(){
        return new AccountsItemProcessor();
}

@Bean
public beanDataItemProccesor beanDataItemProccesor(){
        return new beanDataItemProccesor();
}

@Bean
public BeanAccountItemProcessor BeanAccountItemProcessor(){
       return new BeanAccountItemProcessor();
}
@Bean(name="flatFileItemWriterPartition")
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter<beangen> slaveWriter(
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}") int fromId,@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[toId]}")int toId ) {
      FlatFileItemWriter<beangen> reader = new FlatFileItemWriter<beangen>();
      reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(
          "csv/users.processed" + fromId + "-" + toId + ".csv"));
      //reader.setAppendAllowed(false);
      reader.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<beangen>() {{
        setDelimiter(",");
        setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<beangen>() {{
          setNames(new String[]{"usernetwork","cuenta","atributo"});
        }});
      }});
      return reader;
}
@Bean(name="tempRecordsWriter")
@StepScope
public ListDelegateWriter ListDelegateWriter(@Qualifier("flatFileItemWriterPartition")FlatFileItemWriter<beangen> writer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ListDelegateWriter wri = new ListDelegateWriter();
        wri.setDelegate(writer);

        return wri;
}
@Bean(name = "demoReader")
@StepScope
public ItemReader<beangenerico> formiikreader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fromId']}") int minValue,@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['toId']}") int maxValue){

        MyReader fr = new MyReader(minValue,maxValue);
        return fr;
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
}

@Bean
public Job job(@Qualifier("demoPartitionStep") Step demoPartitionStep) {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(demoPartitionStep)
                .build();
}
…
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at your code, I think your headache is due to all these `ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>>>`. Can you  explain why do you need them? Can you explain what are you trying to achieve (the problem at hand) without referring to Spring Batch (your attempted solution)?

Comment: Well I need it because I will build another object that it will send to the webservice,then each one user have your own id of usernetwork,your own list of account with your attributes within of the ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>>>, and each one of the user have your agent type for identify the form that it will show ex:MRD74, SRD74,ORD74,TRD15,ORD15, each letter is type of the form.The webservice already exist, just Im trying use spring batch for process massive.I hope can you understand my explanation.Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine

Comment: Thanks, but still not clear to me. To be honest with you, you need to review your implementation. I don't see a valid reason to use `ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>>>` in all layers (web controller, business service and DAO + in the item processor of the batch job). Please edit the question and explain the problem at hand before posting your attempted solution: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine , I did what you asked to me

Comment: Thanks. According to your updated description, you really don't need all these `ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>>>`, which I strongly believe is the cause of your issue. You can partition your input in non-overlapping partitions and make each thread process a different partition.

Comment: Ok thanks @MahmoudBenHassine ,you would have some example please, but if you look at my code I changed it for bean but no longer mixed data but does not proccess all data and I do´t know whether my configuration is bad. What is missing in my code? thanks friend.

Comment: It´s worth mentioning that I have rangepartitioner like you said me , I even changed the ThreadLocal<CopyOnWriteArrayList<ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>>> for beans or pojo like in my code updated. Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine

Comment: Yes, you can find an example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#partitioning-sample.

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine, for your reply only that it´s does not process all , what´s wrong ? , I hope can someone give me a light, thanks in advance.